# How to display popup message before deleting a product in php

Tags: javascript, php, popup

```
     <a href='../../include/Query.php? 
     deletepro=yes&proID=".$row['proID']."&proName=".$row['proName']."' onClick= 'confirmation()'><i 
     class='fas fa-trash-alt' style='color:Gray' ></i></a>
```

//Delete Data of a product\

function confirmation
var r= confirm('you want to delete?')
if(r== "true"){
if (isset($_GET['deletepro'])){

```
         if($_GET['deletepro'] == 'yes'  AND $_GET['proID'] !=''){

    //$sql = "DELETE from main where userid =".$_GET['userid'];
    $sql= "UPDATE products  SET proDeleted=1 where proID= ".$_GET['proID'];
    $query=mysqli_query($con, $sql);
    if ($query) {
        echo "<script> alert('".$_GET['proName']." delete Successfully');
        window.location.href = '../admin/pages/products.php';</script>";
    }


    else{
        echo "error while deleting";
    }
    }
    }
    }
    </script>
```

The first popup shows then if a user clicks on ok then delete the product.
I Don't know how to embed or show a popup msg so please someone help to solve my problem. Thanks

Comment: Probably `confirmation()` should be https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/confirm

Answer (score 0):

You can use js delete confirmation as follows:

```
function confirmation() {
    if (!confirm("Do you want to delete")){
       return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: None of this code you've shown uses jQuery